# I want to remove element with tampermonkey userscript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want remove this element from the page by using tampermonkey / greasemonkey userscript, someone help with a code please?

That's the element I wish to erase on **pastebin.com**:

https://pastebin.com/ugPDabHc

This code show up only when I click on " Fight " button so its a hidden element visible only after clicking on the button I'm a total newbie in this, I hope someone can help me

I used adblock extension tool to block it, and it worked very well.. but I want it as a userscript not related to adblock at all

Screenshot from adblock order for block the element:

[image]

I was using this userscript before but not work anymore

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         AutoHealer~
// @version      4.1.2
// @description  [game] Auto healer (and few more things)
// @match        *.org/battle.html*
// @grant        none
// ==/UserScript==

function sendEatRequest(){var a="quality="+$("#foodQuality").val();$.ajax({type:"POST",url:"eat.html",data:a,success:function(a){updateCitizenStatus(a)}})}function sendGiftRequest(){var a="quality="+$("#giftQuality").val();$.ajax({type:"POST",url:"gift.html",data:a,success:function(a){updateCitizenStatus(a)}})}function updateCitizenStatus(a){var b=jQuery.parseJSON(a);$("#foodLimit").html(b.foodLimit),$("#giftLimit").html(b.giftLimit),$("#foodLimit2").html(b.foodLimit),$("#giftLimit2").html(b.giftLimit),$("#wellness").html(b.wellness),$("#healthBar").html(b.wellness),$("#healthProgress .ui-progressbar-value").animate({width:b.wellness+"%"},{queue:!1}),$("#actualHealth").html(b.wellness);var c=$("#consumable"),d=$("#battleSelectable"),e=$("#storage-ammunt");c.find("#foodQ1").html("<b>Q1</b><br>"+b.q1FoodStorage),c.find("#foodQ2").html("<b>Q2</b><br>"+b.q2FoodStorage),c.find("#foodQ3").html("<b>Q3</b><br>"+b.q3FoodStorage),c.find("#foodQ4").html("<b>Q4</b><br>"+b.q4FoodStorage),c.find("#foodQ5").html("<b>Q5</b><br>"+b.q5FoodStorage),c.find("#giftQ1").html("<b>Q1</b><br>"+b.q1GiftStorage),c.find("#giftQ2").html("<b>Q2</b><br>"+b.q2GiftStorage),c.find("#giftQ3").html("<b>Q3</b><br>"+b.q3GiftStorage),c.find("#giftQ4").html("<b>Q4</b><br>"+b.q4GiftStorage),c.find("#giftQ5").html("<b>Q5</b><br>"+b.q5GiftStorage),d.find("#sfoodQ1").html("<b>Q1</b><br>"+b.q1FoodStorage),d.find("#sfoodQ2").html("<b>Q2</b><br>"+b.q2FoodStorage),d.find("#sfoodQ3").html("<b>Q3</b><br>"+b.q3FoodStorage),d.find("#sfoodQ4").html("<b>Q4</b><br>"+b.q4FoodStorage),d.find("#sfoodQ5").html("<b>Q5</b><br>"+b.q5FoodStorage),d.find("#sgiftQ1").html("<b>Q1</b><br>"+b.q1GiftStorage),d.find("#sgiftQ2").html("<b>Q2</b><br>"+b.q2GiftStorage),d.find("#sgiftQ3").html("<b>Q3</b><br>"+b.q3GiftStorage),d.find("#sgiftQ4").html("<b>Q4</b><br>"+b.q4GiftStorage),d.find("#sgiftQ5").html("<b>Q5</b><br>"+b.q5GiftStorage),e.find(".Food-1-amount").text(b.q1FoodStorage),e.find(".Food-2-amount").text(b.q2FoodStorage),e.find(".Food-3-amount").text(b.q3FoodStorage),e.find(".Food-4-amount").text(b.q4FoodStorage),e.find(".Food-5-amount").text(b.q5FoodStorage),e.find(".Gift-1-amount").text(b.q1GiftStorage),e.find(".Gift-2-amount").text(b.q2GiftStorage),e.find(".Gift-3-amount").text(b.q3GiftStorage),e.find(".Gift-4-amount").text(b.q4GiftStorage),e.find(".Gift-5-amount").text(b.q5GiftStorage)}function addDomElements(){var a=$('<div class="foundation-radius fightContainer foundation-base-font mobileBattle"></div>'),b=$('<input type="checkbox" class="smallerBox" id="autoHealBox" name="autoHealBox" style="margin:1px !important;line-height:10px !important;">'),c=$('<label class="checkboxlabel" for="autoHealBox" style="margin-right: 20px;">Auto-heal</label>'),d=$('<input type="checkbox" class="smallerBox" id="removeMaskBox" name="removeMaskBox" checked style="margin:1px !important;line-height:10px !important;">'),e=$('<label class="checkboxlabel" for="removeMaskBox" style="margin-right: 20px;">Remove fight window</label>'),f=$('<input type="checkbox" class="smallerBox" id="hideTopTenBox" name="hideTopTenBox" checked style="margin:1px !important;line-height:10px !important;">'),g=$('<label class="checkboxlabel" for="hideTopTenBox" style="margin-right: 20px;">Hide top-ten</label>'),h=$('<input type="text" id="intervalRefresh" name="intervalRefresh" value="7" style="max-width: 30px;outline: 0px !important; border: 0 !important;">'),i=$('<label class="checkboxlabel" for="intervalRefresh" style="margin-right: 20px;">Battle refresh interval [s]</label>');a.append(d),a.append(e),a.append(b),a.append(c),a.append(f),a.append(g),a.append(h),a.append(i),$(a).insertAfter($('[class="foundation-radius fightContainer foundation-base-font mobileBattle"]')[1]),$("#intervalRefresh").spinner({min:2,max:10,spin:function(a,b){updateRereshInterval(b.value)}}),$("#intervalRefresh").prop("disabled",!0)}function toggleTopTen(a){var b=$(".foundation-style.small-10.columns")[5];a?$(b).css("display","none"):$(b).css("display","block")}function updateRereshInterval(a){for(var b=1;b<99999;b++)window.clearInterval(b);window.setInterval(sendUpdateRequest,1e3*a),window.setInterval(function(){addRecentHits(!0,attackerHits),attackerHits.length>0&&(attackerHits=attackerHits.slice(1))},1e3),window.setInterval(function(){addRecentHits(!1,defenderHits),defenderHits.length>0&&(defenderHits=defenderHits.slice(1))},1e3)}$(document).ready(function(){addDomElements(),$(document).ajaxComplete(function(a,b,c){if("fight.html"===c.url){if(document.getElementById("autoHealBox").checked){var d=parseInt($(b.responseText).find("#healthUpdate").text());if(0===d){var e=parseInt($("#foodLimit2").text()),f=parseInt($("#giftLimit2").text()),g=$("#foodQuality").val(),h=$("#giftQuality").val(),i=$("#sfoodQ"+g).text().replace("Q"+g,""),j=$("#sgiftQ"+h).text().replace("Q"+h,"");e>0&&i>0?sendEatRequest():f>0&&j>0&&sendGiftRequest()}}document.getElementById("removeMaskBox").checked&&($("div.newFightWindow").parent().remove(),$("div.pico-overlay").remove())}}),$("#hideTopTenBox").change(function(){toggleTopTen($(this).is(":checked")?!0:!1)}),$("#refreshInterval").change(function(){$(this).val()})});
```

this user script show like this:

[image]